# Date-range search

Tags: mysql, performance, date-range

Quassnoi and others have posted some related solutions, but they don't apply to this particular case.

In a MySql table with about 2 million records,
(Id int, StartDate date, EndDate date) and some info.
I need to isolate the records that touch a specific date range (From-To) example: Which records touch the month of November

```
SELECT id 
    FROM Records
    WHERE StartDate<="2015-11-30"
      AND EndDate>="2015-11-01"
```

The difference between Start and End dates is normally small, but may be large (more than one year). This is why Quassnoi's previous answer does not work.
I cannot make it to run in a decent time.

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Do the date ranges overlap?  (Not just touch at the end-points.)

Comment: Yes.  The only restrictions is that for every record EndDate >= StartDate.
An example may be bookings in a hotel.
And the query means: Which bookings use rooms in November?

Comment: Your query should run reasonably fast with index on startdate, enddate,id. However, it doesn't seems to able to answer your bookings question. For bookings in November, you need :  where startdate between '2015-11-01' and '2015-12-01' or enddate between '2015-11-01' and '2015-12-01' . You can try use union to see if you can improve speed.

Comment: Bookings that use November may start before November, and may end after November. When an index on startdate, enddate,id is present, is is not used y mysql (or any other sql I have tested).

Answer (score 0):

It is a difficult problem.  No `INDEX` will work well.

However, let me sketch out a workaround that involves an extra table and some extra processing.

1. Pick a time period such as 'month' (as with your example).
2. Build another table that has PRIMARY KEY(month, id) where `id` is the id of the booking.  (I don't think there need to be any other columns.)
3. For each record (in your current table), populate the new table with one or more rows using the booking `id` and the month(s) it partially or fully spans.
4. "Which bookings use rooms in November" should be quite easy and obvious.
5. "Which bookings use rooms between April 28 and May 4 involves looking for ids for both April and May, then checking the actual start/end dates to filter out those that don't apply.

If you use 'week' (instead of 'month'), there will be more rows in the new table, but the selectivity is better -- it is hard to say which is better in the long run.

So, the query becomes something like the following.  (I am assuming $start_date to $end_date are DATEs and are *inclusive*.)

```
SELECT ...
    FROM new_table AS n
    JOIN bookings AS b USING(id)
    WHERE start_date <= n.month + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
      AND n.month <= $end_date
      AND ... same stuff for b. ...
```

Comment: This option sounds good. I will test and post the results here soon.

Answer (score 0):

This tests were performed in : php 5.4 / MySql 5.5.42
Dual SSD Raid-1.

Tables bookings, with almost 2 million records and weeks (more than 2 million records, because some bookings span over 2 or more weeks)

```
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ## id is booking number.
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  /* .  . . . . .  Rest of booking's info */
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `st_end` (`start_date, end_date`),
  KEY `end_date` (`end_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8  COMMENT='A record for each booking';


 CREATE TABLE `weeks` (
   `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `bk_nr` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `week` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
   KEY `week` (`week`),
   KEY `bk_nr` (`bk_nr`)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
 COMMENT='Records indicate that booking (bk_nr) touches week number (week)';
```

Each booking may have several records in "weeks". One for each week that it touches.

Week was generated in php, using date("oW"). It creates year-week, ex: for 2015-03-01 : 201509 (Year 2015 Week 09).

Test results. Searching for bookings that use any day of March-2015. 
Worst first.

0,56 Seconds

        `SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM bookings c
        WHERE c.d_start_date <= "2015-03-31" AND c.d_end_date >= "2015-03-01"
        AND c.id in (
            SELECT w.bk_nr FROM weeks w

            WHERE w.week between 201509 AND 201514
        );`

0,14 Seconds

    `SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM bookings c, weeks w
    WHERE  c.id = w.bk_nr
    AND w.week between 201509 AND 201514
    AND c.d_start_date <= "2015-03-31" AND c.d_end_date >= "2015-03-01";`

And the winner is . . . .

Best: 0,1 seconds

    `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM bookings
    WHERE start_date <= "2015-03-31" AND end_date >= "2015-03-01";`

Looks like MySql has improved from my previous tests (performed in mysql 4.x), and now it knows how to handle this type of queries efficiently.

No need to help it.
(Time was measured by simply "SELECT now()" before and after each query.)
Thank you Rick James for your help.

Comment: In MySql 4.x, 2 Sata disks Raid-10.
Best time: 49 seconds.

Comment: One more difference. Old tables were MyIsam. New tables are InnoDB.